# How do I find the module for a PowerShell cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to setup a VM with Hyper-V. I need to run get-vmserver and some related comdlets, but I can't find what module they are in. When I run:

```
(get-command -name start-transcript).modulename
```

I get a response

```
Microsoft.Powershell.Host
```

But when I run

```
(get-command -name get-vm).modulename
```

I get the response that get-vm is not recognized.

I believe this means I must run import-module with some module name, but I can't find a list of "standard" cmdlets and their modules.

Comment: You have the hyper-v module installed your system? `Get-Command -Module hyper-v`

Comment: Or `get-module -name 'hyper-v'`

Comment: In order to use the hyper-v module you must have hyper-v enabled\installed. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846766(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 2):

That means that PowerShell is not aware of any command called `Get-VM`.

For a command to be recognized, it must either:

- Be defined in the session.
- Be defined in a loaded module.
- Be defined in a module that meets the criteria for auto-loading

Microsoft's modules tend to be well-formed and support auto-loading, so if it were installed, it would be working.

Therefore I strongly suspect you did not install the `Hyper-V` module (which is where `Get-VM` is from).

To see modules that are installed but not necessarily imported, use `Get-Module -ListAvailable`.

But note that if the module is listed there, and is well-formed, the commands would be available in `Get-Command` as well.

#### Demo

Look at a module listed in `Get-Module -ListAvailable` but not listed if you explicitly call `Get-Command -Name`. On my system, I'll use `VpnClient`.

From the output of `Get-Module -ListAvailable` I can see it has a command `Add-VpnConnection`.

If I call `Get-Command -Name Add-VpnConnection`, the call works, and it shows the source of the command as `VpnClient`.

Also, if I now call `Get-Module -Name VpnClient`, it will show up whereas before it didn't.

This is because the module was *implicitly* loaded when `Get-Command` referenced it.

Comment: On my system (the VM I am running with Hyper-V). get-command returns a long list of commands. Get-command -listavailable returns an error: a parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ListAvailable'. I'm using Version 4.

Comment: @Ron the command is `Get-Module -ListAvailable` (not `Get-Command -ListAvailable`). You managed to find the one reference in my answer where I mixed it up! ;)  (thanks, fixed)

Comment: SORRY!!!! But I'm still not clear. I'm trying to create a virtual switch in the VM to connect to my actual network connector in the management OS. With VMWare this was easy and done via a Settings manager. But with Hyper-V it seems quite different.

Comment: @Ron your question doesn't really refer to any of that. I would post a question like that on [sf] or [su] anyway (not here on SO). Your question (and my answer) are generically about PowerShell, and how to discover commands and modules. The conclusion I've drawn is that you do not have the commands you're looking for installed.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that you must run Import-Module and select the Hyper-V module. Make sure that you have installed the Hyper-V feature on your Windows Server. This can be performed in server manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Find-Module -Command YourCmdletName
```

`Find-Module` can find modules that you may not yet have installed, whilst `Get-Command` only checks modules that you have already installed.

`Find-Module` checks all registered repositories, by default, only PSGallery.  You see the list of repositories that `Find-Module` searches with:

```
Get-PSRepository
```

You can register additional PowerShell repositories with

```
Register-PSRepository
```

Once the desired module is identified, you can install it with the `Install-Module` command:

```
Install-Module ModuleName
```